# laravel 5.6 server error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

My website works perfect on `localhost` but when moved to live server which is `Ubuntu 16.04 LTS` I got this error

> [Mon Mar 05 11:11:28.968821 2018] [:error] [pid 19322] [client 156.212.75.255:61635] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php on line 42
>           [Mon Mar 05 11:11:28.968895 2018] [:error] [pid 19322] [client 156.212.75.255:61635] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0
>           [Mon Mar 05 11:11:28.969374 2018] [:error] [pid 19322] [client 156.212.75.255:61635] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) in XXXXXXXXXX/vendor/symfony/finder/Comparator/NumberComparator.php on line 42
>           [Mon Mar 05 11:11:28.969390 2018] [:error] [pid 19322] [client 156.212.75.255:61635] PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0

How can I fix that and what is the right way to remove the public directory?

Comment: What php version that you have on your server?

Comment: php version is 7.0

Comment: I upgraded the php version  now my server php is PHP 7.2.2 and my local version is PHP 7.2.0 i still got same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

follow this link to upgrade php version to 7.2

https://thishosting.rocks/install-php-on-ubuntu/

then run this commands

sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo a2dismod php7.0

sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score 4):

#### disable php7.0

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0
```

#### enable php7.1

```
sudo a2enmod php7.1 #to enable 7.1
```

#### restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the source [code](https://github.com/symfony/finder/blob/master/Comparator/NumberComparator.php#L42).

```
/**
 * @param string|int $test A comparison string or an integer
 *
 * @throws \InvalidArgumentException If the test is not understood
 */
public function __construct(?string $test)
{
```

The `?string`, it's called `Nullable` Type. This feature comes after php `7.1` (see documentation [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)). So you need to upgrade php version on your server. Make sure you get minimum php version `7.1`. Or make it same with your local environment.

Comment: I upgraded the php version as you recommended now my server php is

PHP 7.2.2

and my local version is

PHP 7.2.0

i still got same error

Comment: Yes every thing is ok now i upgraded the php version to 7.2 and run this commands

sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo a2dismod php7.0

 sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: Great! Very glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check your php version, it's very likely that's it:

For ubuntu family:

```
> a2dismod php5.6 #current version
> a2enmod php7.1 #required version ( 7.0, 7.1, 7.2 )
> service apache2 restart
```